# What did my wife write?

Tags: meaning

my wife is Chinese and we had an argument yesterday and she wrote this for herself (see pictures). Unfortunately her handwriting is too hard for me to read and look up (I first tried to look in a kanji dictionary counting the lines etc), can someone help?
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> No Value
>
> Personal Time
>
> 1. Improve work skills
> 2. Spend time on photobooks
> 3. Know more friends
> 4. Spend less time on meaningless housework (literally, maybe means home affairs?)
>    《Invest myself》

Comment: With pleasure : )